# Inject all Kafka Consumers created by a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using the [`ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.html) to create our Kafka [`Consumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html)s.

With the [`ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer#concurrency`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrency(int)) property it is possible to create multiple consumers.

Is it possible in a Spring Boot application to inject all [`Consumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html)s created by the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`? Or is it possible to obtain them somehow after an [`ApplicationEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html)?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why do you need them? Perhaps existing API on the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` and its `getContainers()` will be enough for you. The `KafkaConsumer` is really a volatile object and it can be renewed (replaced) at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need access to the underlying `Consumer` objects? They are managed by the container.

The consumer is available as a parameter in the message listener and is included in published events, but using the `Consumer` API directly is not recommended because such usage might conflict with the container's expectations.

It's ok to use passive APIs, such as getting the end offsets of subscribed topics.